# Cant Find a 2D Circle for Unitys Particle System

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have seen man[image]y people using 2D circles in unity's particle system but I cant find out how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the renderer module you determine what the particles will look like. in the shape module you determine the shape of the emitter and you can select circle.

edit by changing material under 'Renderer' in render mode 'Billboard' you can change whats being rendered

[image]

Comment: Look at this picture (edited question) in the scene view he is using squares for his rocket particle effect but in the game view they are circles. Any idea how to get the circles

Comment: Hmmm, I cant seem to find it. Could you send a picture or something? Thanks :)

Comment: How do I make a cirlce material?

Comment: use gimp or photoshop make a circle with transparent background, create material add texture you created, set render mode to transparent

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Comment: I would really appreciate an example of how to make a circle material, it doesnt work for me :)

Comment: Create a new material, make sure the background is transparent and then set the render mode to transparent, add in your texture to the 'albedo' box

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the shape, you should be able to select the cone and rotate it so it faces the camera. It will look like a circle